# Check Rows in a game of tic tac toe that is four layers, four wide by four tall

Tags: java, arrays, loops, tic-tac-toe

```
public boolean checkWin() {
    if(states[0][0][0] == 1 && states[0][0][1] == 1 && states[0][0][2] ==1 && states[0][0][3] ==1) { // Checks 0th layer, 0th row
        return true; 
    }
    else if (states[0][1][0] == 1 && states[0][1][1] == 1 && states[0][1][2] ==1 && states[0][1][3] ==1) { // Checks 0th layer, 1st row
        return true;
    }
    else if (states[0][2][0] == 1 && states[0][2][1] == 1 && states[0][2][2] ==1 && states[0][2][3] ==1) { // Checks 0th layer, 2nd row
        return true;
    }
    else if (states[0][3][0] == 1 && states[0][3][1] == 1 && states[0][3][2] ==1 && states[0][3][3] ==1) { // Checks 0th layer, 3rd row
        return true;
    }
}
```

This code is hard coded to check the 0 th layer, and the 4 rows on that layer. I could hard code the rest but of course that would be very time consuming and bad code. When I try and make a loop it stops after three clicks

```
public boolean checkWin() {

    for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
        if(states[0][0][i] == 1){ // Checks 0th layer, all rows
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is how I tried to make the loop, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly your question is?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a 3d tic-tac-toe game, 4 units wide * 4 units high * 4 units deep?

Comment: its a 4x4x4 tic tac toe, when clicked the token state turns to either 1(for player one) or 2(for player 2), I need to write the loop(s) that check the board to see if a player has won the game (fill a row, column, etc). The top code works, but it is hard coded to just check the 4 rows in the bottom layer.

Comment: I think something is messed up somewhere else in my code cause after 3 clicks it says game over and that someone won

Comment: To avoid making 304 separate checks, you could pass the co-ordinates of the cell that was last played in, to this method.  Then you'd have at most 21 other cells to check.

Answer (score 1):

This game is a nice example of how a data driven approach can simplify our code. Consider:

- there are 64 cells, that can be empty or contain a token; the number of tokens depends on the number of players. This can be represented as a one dimensional array of 64 elements.
- the cells are in 76 rows. This can be represented as a array of 76 rows of 4, each cell containing a subscript for an element in the first array. (In C or C++ you could also store pointers, in Java you can store references).

To check for a winning row, you can then just iterate through the 76 rows, and check if every cell in a row of the first array has the value you assigned to one player or the other.

Comment: This type of problem is perfect for early programming assignments. Hence I thought it better to let the OP work that trivial step out.

Answer (score -1):

Your current code checks only for rows in the third dimension. You should check the other dimensions as well:

```
for(int i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j < 4;j++) {
        if(
          (states[i][j][0] == 1 && states[i][j][1] == 1 && states[i][j][2] == 1 && states[i][j][3] == 1) ||
          (states[i][0][j] == 1 && states[i][1][j] == 1 && states[i][2][j] == 1 && states[i][3][j] == 1) ||
          (states[0][i][j] == 1 && states[1][i][j] == 1 && states[2][i][j] == 1 && states[3][i][j] == 1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

You could make it more abstract than this by looping also over the last dimension, but that'd require boolean variables or break/continue statements so I think this is about as clear as the code is going to get.

Comment: Don't forget that there are 4 body diagonals, and also 24 diagonals that are orthogonal to one of the cube's dimensions.  I don't think you've accounted for those.

Answer (score -1):

You need to rewrite you loop like so:

```
public boolean checkWin() {

    for (int layer=0; layer<=3; layer++) {
        for (int row=0; row<=3; row++) {
          if(states[layer][row][0] == 1){
              return true; 
          }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This logic checks only for row based wins. Note however that in a TicTacToe, you also need to check for Column based win and diagonal win.

Comment: This will prematurely return true if any single element in the row is `1`, it does not check to make sure that all elements in the row are `1`.

Comment: Good catch. It's more complex than just checking rows, columns and diagonals. What if there is a winning scenario across layers? or worse a diagonal on the z-axis.

Comment: Correct, it is non-trivial to test for wins in a 4x4x4 tic-tac-toe board.